# Using Firebase Cloud Messaging REST API - "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"

Tags: firebase, coldfusion, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use the firebase REST api with coldfusion. My code looks as such:

```
<cfhttp method="post" url="https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myapp_name/messages:send" 
                result="httpResponse">  

    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="#serverkey#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(stFields)#">
</cfhttp>
```

I get a `"error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.` response. I've tried just about every key listed on the firebase console for `serverkey`. Am I sending the wrong header?

Comment: FCM v1 sends don't use a server key. You can find out more about this [here](https://medium.com/@ThatJenPerson/authenticating-firebase-cloud-messaging-http-v1-api-requests-e9af3e0827b8).